# How to Join two tables with conditions

Tags: r

**Question**
How would I mutate Lookup_Values with the corresponding factor from Factors table. Where the factor would be if n is greater than or equal to Factors$lowN, but less than highN. This is similar to Vlookup(...,True)

```
lookup_values <- data.frame(n = c(4,7,15))
```

| n |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 7 |
| 15 |

```
factors<- data.frame(lowN=c(1,9),
                         highN=c(9,20),
                         factor=c(1,2))
```

| lowN | highN | factor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 1 |
| 9 | 20 | 2 |

Desired output would be

| n | Factor |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 15 | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use non-equi join from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(lookup_values)[factors, Factor := factor, on = .(n >= lowN, n < highN)]
```

-output

```
lookup_values
#    n Factor
#1:  4      1
#2:  7      1
#3: 15      2
```

---

Or using `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
fuzzy_left_join(lookup_values, factors, by = c("n" = "lowN", "n" = "highN"), 
   match_fun = list(`>=`, `<`)) %>%
 select(n, Factor = factor)
#   n Factor
#1  4      1
#2  7      1
#3 15      2
```